# General-purpose bootstrappers for chaining multiple "packages"?

Tags: .net, deployment, wix, installation, bootstrapper

I've been playing around with [dotNetInstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/) for some time now. It's a great general-purpose bootstrapper that can handle *most* of your bootstrapping needs. It's a little dodgy on getting install progress but that is to be expected(Aside from Microsoft's installers (Visual Studio 2005 and up), I have not seen any setup application that was able to report progress from an external packages).

We've been writing our own home-brew general purpose bootstrapper that is more customized to our organization's deployment strategy. We've used dNi to bootstrap our own bootstrapper. (Install .NET and Windows Installer 4.5)

Anyway, aside from dotNetInstaller, are there any other candidates for a general-purpose bootstrapper? We've looked into [BURN](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2009/7/14/Lets-talk-about-Burn) and I think it's a step into the right direction but it is still in its infancy.

Side note: Microsoft bootstrappers are kinda nice! I've sniffed around their XML files and found inspiration on how to design a general-purpose bootstrapper. Do you guys know what bootstrapper Microsoft is using? Particularly for the Visual Studio 2005, 2008 and 2010 installers.

Comment: I believe the .NET4 installer used the code that became Burn and I'm pretty sure the main guy on the WiX/Burn project is working for the Visual Studio team now. I can't remember what VS2010 used though.

Answer (score 0):

We use the bootstrapper that ships with [MSI Factory](http://www.indigorose.com/products/msi-factory) from Indigo Rose. A license for MSI Factory is around $500, which is pretty cheap compared to the cost of writing and testing something in-house. (We purchased the license just for the bootstrapper and use it standalone, MSI Factory itself is pretty ugly)